# how to specify a hierarchical mixed model with two factors nested within participant that are crossed with each other

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I've read a bunch of questions and answers here about how to specify models and some tutorial walk throughs and I still not sure how to deal with my data structure.  I want, obviously, to avoid any hint of pseudoreplication.

I'm trying to test for brain-behavior correlations in some fMRI data.  I have 34 clusters/ROIs that came from another analysis (independent, I hope, since it did not involve the behavioral measure to generate them).

I have 37 participants, 12 runs per participant (i.e., a run is a single session of neuroimaging data).  For a few participants there are only 6 runs.

I have three experimental variables.  Levels of variable A apply to an entire run, while levels of variables B and C apply to trials within a run.  There are three levels of A and two of B and C.

I am trying to specify a model in which the contrast over levels in variable B in the brain data for a run is regressed on the same contrast in the behavioral data. I also want to know how this is modulated by levels of A and C.

I started with:

```
model <- lmer(B_contrast_brain ~ B_contrast_behavior*A*C + (1|subject/cluster), data=data)
```

I was getting some p-values that feel implausibly low to me, so I was trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. One thing I realized: because I have two levels of C per run, run is also a grouping variable nested within subject.  But I'm not sure of the correct way to specify that.

My best guess is:

```
  model <- lmer(B_contrast_brain ~ B_contrast_behavior*A*C + (1|subject/cluster) + (1|subject/run), data=data)
```

But I'm not sure.  When I do that my p-values inch into the realm of plausibility, although a few of the effects are still very strong.

So my questions are:

1. Is the above the right specification?
2. Is there anything else that pops out that I'm doing wrong that could lead to spuriously strong effects?

Edit: I should add that since I asked this question I realized that I was getting the singular fit warning.  Since paring down my fixed effects is not making that warning go away, this must be to do with how I specified my random effects.  This might explain p-values that still feel implausibly low, but I guess I don't understand why I don't have enough data to have both cluster and run be random effects, when I have 34 clusters and 12 runs per subject, with cluster and run fully crossed.

Edit 2, per request:

Here is the output of summary for the first model. `rel` is what I have been calling B, `type` is A, and `taught` is C.

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: winsorized_rel_brain ~ rel_behavior * type * taught + (1 | subject/cluster)
   Data: all_data_dx

REML criterion at convergence: 71101.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.0352 -0.3851 -0.0614  0.3395  5.7847 

Random effects:
 Groups          Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 cluster:subject (Intercept) 0.003915 0.06257 
 subject         (Intercept) 0.010999 0.10488 
 Residual                    0.771609 0.87841 
Number of obs: 27466, groups:  cluster:subject, 1153; subject, 37

Fixed effects:
                             Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 6.153e-02  2.170e-02  7.076e+01   2.836 0.005957 ** 
rel_behavior                4.071e-02  1.489e-02  2.706e+04   2.734 0.006264 ** 
typeN                      -8.669e-02  1.847e-02  2.712e+04  -4.693 2.70e-06 ***
typeY                      -1.113e-03  1.849e-02  2.707e+04  -0.060 0.951981    
taughtU                    -1.387e-01  1.835e-02  2.706e+04  -7.556 4.29e-14 ***
rel_behavior:typeN         -5.066e-02  2.023e-02  2.708e+04  -2.504 0.012283 *  
rel_behavior:typeY         -1.931e-02  2.231e-02  2.711e+04  -0.866 0.386571    
rel_behavior:taughtU       -9.047e-02  2.336e-02  2.693e+04  -3.872 0.000108 ***
typeN:taughtU               2.093e-01  2.617e-02  2.707e+04   7.998 1.31e-15 ***
typeY:taughtU               7.923e-02  2.622e-02  2.707e+04   3.021 0.002518 ** 
rel_behavior:typeN:taughtU  7.945e-02  3.394e-02  2.695e+04   2.341 0.019227 *  
rel_behavior:typeY:taughtU  1.676e-01  3.440e-02  2.711e+04   4.874 1.10e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) rl_bhv typeN  typeY  taghtU rl_b:N rl_b:Y rl_b:U typN:U typY:U r_:N:U
rel_behavir  0.028                                                                      
typeN       -0.421 -0.034                                                               
typeY       -0.420 -0.034  0.493                                                        
taughtU     -0.423 -0.034  0.497  0.497                                                 
rl_bhvr:tyN -0.021 -0.734  0.101  0.023  0.025                                          
rl_bhvr:tyY -0.020 -0.660  0.022  0.103  0.023  0.482                                   
rl_bhvr:tgU -0.017 -0.649  0.021  0.023  0.018  0.468  0.434                            
typeN:tghtU  0.297  0.023 -0.705 -0.348 -0.701 -0.069 -0.016 -0.011                     
typeY:tghtU  0.296  0.025 -0.348 -0.705 -0.700 -0.018 -0.074 -0.014  0.491              
rl_bhvr:N:U  0.011  0.449 -0.061 -0.014 -0.012 -0.607 -0.292 -0.683 -0.025  0.009       
rl_bhvr:Y:U  0.013  0.428 -0.014 -0.067 -0.012 -0.310 -0.651 -0.670  0.008 -0.015  0.454
```

Here is the output for the second:

```
 Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: winsorized_rel_brain ~ rel_behavior * type * taught + (1 | subject/cluster) +      (1 | subject/run)
   Data: all_data_dx

REML criterion at convergence: 68406.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.4126 -0.3985 -0.0264  0.3608  6.9236 

Random effects:
 Groups          Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 cluster.subject (Intercept) 0.000e+00 0.0000000
 run.subject     (Intercept) 1.091e-01 0.3303322
 subject         (Intercept) 0.000e+00 0.0000000
 subject.1       (Intercept) 1.638e-10 0.0000128
 Residual                    6.784e-01 0.8236462
Number of obs: 27466, groups:  cluster:subject, 1153; run:subject, 443; subject, 37

Fixed effects:
                             Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 5.231e-02  2.976e-02  5.206e+02   1.758 0.079394 .  
rel_behavior                4.339e-02  1.890e-02  1.869e+04   2.296 0.021689 *  
typeN                      -9.501e-02  4.216e-02  5.238e+02  -2.253 0.024652 *  
typeY                      -7.202e-03  4.223e-02  5.235e+02  -0.171 0.864643    
taughtU                    -1.394e-01  1.722e-02  2.702e+04  -8.096 5.93e-16 ***
rel_behavior:typeN         -1.067e-01  2.563e-02  1.894e+04  -4.165 3.13e-05 ***
rel_behavior:typeY         -7.256e-02  2.801e-02  2.008e+04  -2.590 0.009597 ** 
rel_behavior:taughtU        4.737e-03  3.241e-02  1.452e+04   0.146 0.883789    
typeN:taughtU               2.160e-01  2.465e-02  2.709e+04   8.761  < 2e-16 ***
typeY:taughtU               8.743e-02  2.475e-02  2.714e+04   3.532 0.000413 ***
rel_behavior:typeN:taughtU  5.267e-02  4.664e-02  1.504e+04   1.129 0.258884    
rel_behavior:typeY:taughtU  1.129e-01  4.516e-02  1.769e+04   2.500 0.012416 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) rl_bhv typeN  typeY  taghtU rl_b:N rl_b:Y rl_b:U typN:U typY:U r_:N:U
rel_behavir  0.027                                                                      
typeN       -0.706 -0.019                                                               
typeY       -0.705 -0.019  0.498                                                        
taughtU     -0.290 -0.045  0.205  0.204                                                 
rl_bhvr:tyN -0.020 -0.737  0.056  0.014  0.033                                          
rl_bhvr:tyY -0.018 -0.675  0.013  0.056  0.030  0.498                                   
rl_bhvr:tgU -0.020 -0.734  0.014  0.014  0.028  0.541  0.495                            
typeN:tghtU  0.202  0.031 -0.290 -0.143 -0.698 -0.076 -0.021 -0.019                     
typeY:tghtU  0.202  0.031 -0.142 -0.290 -0.695 -0.023 -0.095 -0.019  0.486              
rl_bhvr:N:U  0.014  0.510 -0.039 -0.010 -0.019 -0.698 -0.344 -0.695 -0.025  0.013       
rl_bhvr:Y:U  0.014  0.527 -0.010 -0.036 -0.020 -0.388 -0.691 -0.718  0.014 -0.016  0.499
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

Comment: Please include the output of `summary(model)` for both models. Also please can you let us know how you determine whether a p-value is plausible ?

Comment: @RobertLong thanks for the engagement!  I added both outputs.  As for the p-values, if asked to weigh the likelihood that an interaction in my experimental variables (e.g. typeN:taughtU ) is determining a contrast in brain activation estimable with such precision, versus the likelihood that I'm making a mistake in reasoning somewhere, I think "I'm making a mistake" is more plausible.

Comment: Specifically, I think my mistake may be about the degrees of freedom in my denominator, but I can't figure out how to correctly specify them.  A domain expert also pointed me to this blogpost, which may be affecting my inference as well: https://mumfordbrainstats.tumblr.com/post/126904300281/inconspicuous-double-dipping?fbclid=IwAR0nRVSqJQ1b0K6FIos7IfLJw5T6kXKkFM6tOu01TL2sU6Kk5XmxKrKMQqI

Comment: The 2nd model is singular. As for the denomnator degress of freedom, in a mixed model this is an approximation at best and woefully wrong at worst and underlines why I recommend not using p-values at all - they are little more than a test of sample size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description given it does sound as though you have repeated measures within `run`, which is not accounted for in the first model. However, the 2nd model:

```
B_contrast_brain ~ B_contrast_behavior*A*C + (1|subject/cluster) + (1|subject/run)
```

has the following features:

- fixed effects for `B_contrast_behavior`, `A`, `C` and all the interactions
- random intercepts for `subject` and also for `cluster` varying within levels of `subject`
- random intercepts for `subject` (again) and also for `run` varying within levels of `subject`.

So, you have specified random intercepts for `subject` twice, which may very well be the cause of the singular fit for the 2nd model. In order to just fit random intercepts for `subject` once you can use:

```
B_contrast_brain ~ B_contrast_behavior*A*C + (1|subject/cluster) + (1|subject:run)
```

where we specify random intercepts for `run` varying within levels of `subject` but without re-specifying random intercepts for `subject` again.

As for the p-values, in a mixed model these are approximations at best, so I would avoid them. Also, since you appear to have quite a large sample size, with rather small variance components for `subject` and `cluster` (based on the first model output) small p-values are to be expected.

Comment: Thank you!  Interestingly, when I run your suggested model with my winsorized DV (I didn't winsorize very aggressively; I brought the tails in to about 4 SD) I still got a singular fit that this time failed to converge, but when I ran it on my standardized DV with no winsorization it was fine.  I was only winsorizing as an attempt to eliminate the possibility that (really large) deviations from normality of the residuals in the model were the source of my strong effects.

Comment: On reflection, the strongest effects here are expected,  because they are not interactions with the behavior variable, but rather another way of representing contrasts that I also ran whole brain, and found effects in -- in different clusters, but still, if the three way interaction between A and B and C was powerful enough to generate a bunch of clusters that survived correction for multiple comparisons, it's not surprising that I see it reflected in a different way in my data here.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you describe your alternatives to p-values recommendations? Do you recommend confidence intervals?  Some kind of bootstrappy simulation test?

Comment: I didn't recommend an alternative to p-values. I don't need to know the probability of observing my data if the null hypothesis is in fact true, and that's all a p-value tells me.